# How to convert base64 string into public key?

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, rsa

I tried using below snippets

```
stringToPublicKey()
{
byte[]  strByte = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(string);
KeyFactory  keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(strByte);
PrivateKey  returnKey = keyFact.generatePrivate(x509KeySpec);
return returnKey; 
}   

java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
```

Then i tried with another keySpec eg. X509EncodedKeySpec
but still getting same error.

My aim is to sign the data with given public key

```
    // Compute digest
    MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    byte[] digest = sha1.digest(data);

    // Encrypt digest
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, stringtoPublicKey(key_in_string));
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(digest);
```

But challenge is not getting authenticate ??
Any clue ???

thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot sign with a public key, only with a private key (which you do seem to try and generate). And as you haven't show the actual input of your `stringToPublicKey` method (which should be called differently) we cannot see what goes wrong.

Comment: PS I missed this one as it only had the RSA tag, instead of some more generic tags. Try and use tags with a lot of followers.